# MySQL Update Multiple Rows in Large Table

Tags: mysql, innodb, update

I have a large InnoDB MySQL database table. I would like to run this query against the database table:

```
Update myBigTable Set someColumn=x WHERE userId = 7 OR userId = 88 OR userId = 22 OR userId = 99;
```

The exact contents of the where clause is dynamic. Through a web front end, an administrator checks one or more users who they want to update via this query.

However, when the above query is run, mysql usually returns:

```
#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

So I'm trying to find some way to refactor my sql query so that it doesn't need to do a table lock. The 'someColumn' that is being updated and the userId both have indices defined.

I first tried:

```
Update myBigTable Set someColumn=x WHERE userId IN (7, 88, 22, 99);
```

However, the same problem persisted. I know that I can do four separate queries like:

```
Update myBigTable Set someColumn=x WHERE userId = 7;
Update myBigTable Set someColumn=x WHERE userId = 88;
Update myBigTable Set someColumn=x WHERE userId = 22;
Update myBigTable Set someColumn=x WHERE userId = 99;
```

The above approach does work, but it requires four separate queries (and in the worst case, a user could spawn 150 queries based on our current UI design - this number could grow over time as well).

What is the best practice for doing a sql update statement in MySQL Innodb to update multiple rows in a large table to the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
and see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded
increasing the lock timeout period could solve the issue. 
Apparently default is 50seconds. Which is maybe enough for all of the rows with userid=99, but not enough for rows with 99,22,88 or 7 userid. 
Just speculation.

Comment: I was really hoping to find a way to fundamentally change my query to make it not dependent on the timeout period. Even with an increased timeout, end users will probably not want to wait 50+ seconds for the operation to complete.

Comment: Is your userID indexed?

Comment: Yes, both userId and someColumn are indexed in two separate indices (not a composite).

Comment: How are they indexed? Both (userID, someColumn) or an index for UserID and another index for someColumn?

Comment: One index for userId and a second index for someColumn

Comment: Are there any temporary tables created in the process maybe? Like you would have if there's a join involved? I've had a situation where doing multiple queries instead of one resulted in much better performance, but there was an obvious join involved.

Comment: Try doing an explain on your query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html

Comment: Also since your someColumn is indexed, the slowness could be due to the index needing to be updated since you are changing it. Do you really need this index?

Comment: Go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284365/when-does-mysql-attempt-to-update-an-index-for-a-column   Look at the time for indexed vs non indexed updated. 10k updates of an indexed column with a new value:
A:  76.8 seconds
B: 126.7 seconds

10k updates of a non-indexed column with a new value:
A: 27.6 seconds
B: 22.0 seconds